# How to determine if a Matlab function returns no values?

Tags: matlab, reflection, metaprogramming

f.m:

```
function [] = f(the_only_argument)
% Do awesome things here
end
```

g.m:

```
function [value] = g(the_only_argument)
% Do awesome things here
value = awesome_value;
end
```

Is there some sort of ReturnsNothing, such that:

```
assert(ReturnsNothing(@f) & ~ReturnsNothing(@g))
```

P.S. I want to be able to call `arrayfun(@f, [1,1,1])`, which currently returns an error:

```
??? Error using ==> f
Too many output arguments.
```

Comment: Second part (BTW, how is it related to the first?): you can't pass input arguments (which is what `arrayfun` tries to do) to a function that accepts no input arguments

Comment: Couldn't you just return `NaN` and use that?

Comment: I applologize for a mistake in the question: instead f() it should be f(the_only_arg).

Comment: @mezhaka: I am unable to reproduce your problem, you can use `f` with arrayfun. How do you call `arrayfun`?

Comment: also unable to reproduce, unless you are calling `arrayfun` with an output e.g `out = arrayfun(@f, [1,1,1])`, in which case removing the output e.g. `arrayfun(@f, [1,1,1])` would solve this

Comment: I did call it with an output parameter: `out = arrayfun(@f, [1,1])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do `nargout('f')` and `nargout('g')` do what you need?

Be careful if you have functions with a variable number of output arguments, as `nargout` will return a negative number for that special case.

Answer (score 3):

### Second part

`arrayfun(@f, [1,1,1])` throws the error above as `f` has no input(s) defined, and `arrayfun` will call `f` for each value in the array (using that value as an input). so the error is identical to that which would be caused by `f(1)`

If you need a funciton to run in `arrayfun` which does not take an input you can wrap it in an anonymous function which junks the input.
For example

```
arrayfun(@(~)f,[1,1,1])
```

causes no errors, as **`arrayfun` doesn't require outputs!**

### First part

[`nargout`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) can be used outside of a function to check how many defined outputs it has by passing a string containing the function name

e.g. using functions from question

```
nargout('f')

ans =

     0

nargout('g')

ans =

     1
```

Furthermore if [`varargout`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) is present it counts it as a single output but returns a negative value to indicate its presence

for example with the following function

```
function [value,varargout] = h()
...code
end
```

it returns

```
nargout('h')

ans =

     -2
```

Comment: I sincerely applologize for a mistake in the question: instead f() it should be f(the_only_arg). And instead of 'Too many input arguments.' it should be 'Too many output arguments.'

Comment: no worries, in which case I can't reproduce with Matlab 2013a